# Handle dynamically create inputs with jQuery (/ PHP)

Tags: php, jquery

I've a website where the user have to add as much as he wants `<input />`, like:

```
Company: <input type="text" name="company[]" /> Participation: <input type="text" name="participation[]" />
Company: <input type="text" name="company[]" /> Participation: <input type="text" name="participation[]" />
Company: <input type="text" name="company[]" /> Participation: <input type="text" name="participation[]" />
```

In my PHP backend I check if all works, and I will also use jQuery Validation, but if something go wrong, how can I rewrite this dynamically added forms?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Don't you know how to create and insert elements to the DOM?

Comment: Yes, I know how to append it to my DOM (DOM = document html?). My problem is that I will send this inputs and I need to check it if all validates. If not, I'll redirect to the page to edit the content another time but if the input has been created dynamically I don't know how to access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it now. You can recreate the form elements with PHP. You get all the input values in `$companies = $_GET['company']`. It contains an array of values.

If you want to recreate the form elements, you can loop over this array (assuming you somehow sanitized the input), example:

```
<?php
// $companies and $participations should have the same length
$companies = $_GET['company'];
$participations = $_GET['participation'];

// sanitizing, validation
//...

$count = count($companies);
?>

<?php for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++): ?>
    Company: <input type="text" name="company[]" value="<?php echo $companies[i]; ?>"/>
    Participation: <input type="text" name="participation[]" value="<?php echo $participations[i]; ?>"/>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the form in some sort of session data (pass the form as a string to PHP or save the form string to a cookie).  And then you can rewrite after submission if needed.